# How to add a Tomcat server to Eclipse when the verison is not recognized

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to add a Tomcat server to Eclipse Neon. The drop-down list for servers to select has 8.0 and 9.0. I select 8.0 and click Next. The current version of Tomcat is 8.5.12 and Eclipse won't accept that. Please see the screen snip included here. 
[image]

Comment: Apparently this has been fixed in the latest version of WTP, see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494936

Comment: Thanks to you, @MalcolmSmith .